# Move Email with special attachments to another folder Outlook 2010 with powershell

Tags: email, powershell, outlook, exchange-server

Does anyone know if it it possible to move a received email with attachments, other than .pdf, ex. .txt files to antoher folder than the inbox in Outlook 2010?

I can't find something about "sort by attchement" via powershell.

I hope some of you have some inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a similar task recently and learnt from this tutorial, which includes a script you can download to modify for your needs:

http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2010/01/writing-simple-scripted-process-to.html